# node.js Examples

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any useful examples of node.js (such as a guestbook or chat room)?

Comment: +1 The question is a solid one, just worded a bit poorly. There isn't as much documentation on `node.js` that's easy to use for beginners as there is for javascript in general.

Comment: I agree with Raynos. I am new to node.js and I am trying to learn by finding a repository of examples; which is hard to come by. There are a lot of folks on stackoverflow like Anna (who silly closed this question) with a lot of points but very little ...

Comment: @chrisjlee It looks like you posted the same url as this page. Which page from Programmers.SE were you trying to post here?

Comment: Sorry this other question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974083/could-someone-give-me-an-example-of-node-js-application?lq=1

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't have been closed. I came across this question because I was asking the same.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Read about what I did to make it here: http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/lets-make-a-twitter-clone-in-node-js

Check out the source code here: https://github.com/tglines/nodrr

Comment: ... **note**, this is no longer a twitter clone :)

Comment: The link to nodrr.com is now broken.

Answer (score 8):

There are some useful introductory videos on node at the Node.js Camp website that helped me get my head round things. Particularly the Introduction to Node video by Ryan Dahl (creator of Node.js) where he codes a basic chat server on the spot. Also the videos about Tim Caswell's game client are pretty impressive.

http://camp.nodejs.org/videos/

You may also want to look at the socket.io example on Tim Caswell's 'How To Node' blog if you're interested in a simple chat server.

You didn't say how proficient you were in Javascript but Tim has written a couple of interesting articles that explains some Javascript fundamentals using object graphs. Helps explain some novel concepts such as the prototype chain and closures.

http://howtonode.org

Comment: The camp link appears to be broken. I *think* this moight be the same link (using the wayback machine) http://web.archive.org/web/20110214161106/http://camp.nodejs.org/videos/

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [chat](http://chat.nodejs.org/) along with its [source code](http://github.com/ry/node_chat/tree/master).

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway for your link to Chat

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of a bunch of applications created using node.js that already exist. Perhaps this would be a nice place to start --

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node

Answer (score 3):

DailyJS has a tutorial series about building an app with node.js: http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa

Answer (score 3):

[Pedro Teixeira](http://twitter.com/#!/pedrogteixeira) walks his viewers through creating several parts of a web application at [Node Tuts](http://nodetuts.com/). The code to go with his screencasts can be found on his [Github page](https://github.com/pgte). They mostly deal with Express and Mongoose, but there are plenty of other subjects and code samples there.